# cache the database result in txt file and how to output it?

Tags: php

eg: `$results = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM article');` now I want to put the result in a text file. Then :

```
 $filepath = 'test.txt';
 if (is_file($filepath)) {
   echo file_get_contents($filepath);
 } else {
   // read the databse, and stored the result to the test.txt.
 }
```

1. How to wirite the else part?
2. I want to echo the content in list style. how should I do?

Thank you

Comment: what are reasons for using such cache?

Comment: the page is a static page, only have two parts read other site's data. so i want to put the data readed form other site to a text file. then invoke it.

Answer (score 4):

I really wouldn't.

Your filesystem 'cache' is likely to be slower than the database, and introduces extra bonus consistency problems on top of the added complexity.

If you have expensive, complex queries, look at putting the cached results in another database table, or memcache, or optimising/denormalising the database to make the query faster.

Comment: chaching the result of a query into a cache file makes it even slower then getting it from the database? can you point to resources that proves this? I was about to do this for my site as well.

Comment: @Krike reading from disk is about the slowest thing you can do, it's much more performant to store it in memory. Storing it in a database instead on a file on disk will make the database optimize it and store it in memory if needed.

Comment: Indeed. Although modern OSes will try to optimise/cache file access in various ways to avoid hitting the disk when possible, it's still unlikely to gain you anything. Are you actually experiencing particularly slow database connections for some reason?

Comment: wow we've been caching query results in cache files at work for so long ... but we have most of the clients sites installed on our own server, so I guess they are optimized for this ...

Comment: I purchased this cache class -> http://codecanyon.net/item/caching-class/69006 I guess that's not a good thing to use? So I guess I have to make views for the database and query that?

Comment: @krike views won't help you. If there are any problems with serer load you have, **a profiling** should be done first and some query optimizations followed. It's quite weird to optimize something blindly, not knowing the real cause of the problem, don't you think so?

Comment: Cached HTML is useful when you've got really complex pages that take a long time to generate (certainly not for something as simple as a list of `SELECT title FROM article`) and which are read a lot. For that case, I'd look at memcache instead of dumping them onto filesystem though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at an opcode cache such as APC. This will handle the cache expiry for you, and will be significantly faster than either this filesystem cache or a SQL query.

I often use this technique handle slow queries, from read often, write little databases.

Comment: I doubt he's really need that. From the way the question phrased one can tell that this is not a real problem but rather some delusion being the reason.